# Rails: Omniauth - "The parameter app_id is required"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I'm following this railscast tutorial to set up omniauth for facebook authentication on my rails project: http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?autoplay=true. I'm 4 minutes in and all I've done so far is bundle the gem `omniauth-facebook` and added,

omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['my id here...'], ENV['my secret code here...']

end
```

and then when I go to `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook` I get an error saying `The parameter app_id is required`.

Comment: Did you actually add the ENV variables to your environment? Checked here are there? Restarted server?

Comment: Yes the ENV variables are there, took them out before posting here of course. And I just restated my server. But I'm unsure what you mean by "Checked here are there?"

Comment: Sorry, typo. I mean if you checked the env variables are actually in your environment (ie you added them to ~/.bashrc but forgot to ``source ~/.bashrc`` would be a common mistake). You can stop your server, and, in  the same console, type ``printenv | grep FACEBOOK_APP_ID`` or whatever your env variable is named

Answer (score 9):

Oh, now I see: you need to define environment variables to store your `facebook_app_id` and `facebook_secret`. You add them to your environment like this (assuming unix-like system):

Add this to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file (or equivalent):

```
export FACEBOOK_APP_ID='your_id_here'
export FACEBOOK_SECRET='your_secret_here'
```

Then open a new terminal to be sure they get loaded in the environment.

At last, in your `omniauth.rb` initializer you type exactly:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
end
```

Read more about the topic [here](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/managing-environment-configuration-variables-in-rails), for example.

You can also use dotenv gem to handle environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the keys on the ENV variable as dgilperez says, or remove the ENV and write it directly.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'FACEBOOK_SECRET'
end
```

if you put the source code in a public repo (like github), use the ENV variable as it's more secure.

Comment: This will help who are not good with Unix like OS or Linux distos.